# JSch to add private key from a string

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, private-key

I have the contents of the key pair file for SFTP as a string. I need to use JSch to add the contents, but `addIdentity` only accepts a file path. Is there anyway I can do this?

I see that the `KeyPair` class has a method -

```
KeyPair load(JSch jsch, byte[] bytes, byte[] bytes1)
```

I'm not sure what this does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an [`addIdentity` overload that takes the key from a buffer](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#addIdentity-java.lang.String-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-):

```
public class JSch {
    ...
    public void addIdentity(String name, byte[]prvkey, byte[]pubkey, byte[] passphrase)
```

---

See also [Java SFTP client that takes private key as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31931574/850848).

For an example of implementation, see [JSch: addIdentity from private key stored on hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50859100/850848#50930385).

See also [Loading private key from string or resource in Java JSch in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56758040/850848) for a format of the key in the buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the following

```
String privateKeyValue = "You private Key String";
jsch.addIdentity(null, privateKeyValue.getBytes(), null, null);
```